# Configuration of wamp and mod_perl

Tags: perl, wamp, mod-perl

I need to configure Wamp Server to run [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) but, I am unable to find `mod_perl` module for wamp. The command I found didn't work :

```
C:\> ppm install  http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/mod_perl-2.0.ppd
```

I'm getting an error :

```
ppm install failed: 404 Not Found
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Hi, that repository is down, perhaps gone for good. Which version of Perl do you have? ActiveState, Strawberry or something else?

Comment: I would suggest Strawberry Perl rather than AS, that's also quite an old version. Install from source http://perl.apache.org/download/source.html